# In Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, how can I register a DLL file on Windows 7 64-bit computer using a Custom Action command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, dllregistration

From the Window's command prompt I can register a DLL like so:

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\regsvr32 C:\User\Desktop\msxml4.dll
```

(I have a 64-bit computer, but need to use the 32-bit version of MSXML4).

Also I can make a custom action folder in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013. Here is image of folder:

[image: Custom Action Folder]

However, I would like my custom action install method (or any other alternative) to automatically register the MSXML4 on regsvr32 (instead of me manually doing it) when I run the setup that I have build. How can achieve this?

I have not been able to find much documentation on Visual Studio Custom Actions online, and am fairly unfamiliar with the tool in the first place.

I will have to work with Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 for various reasons and can't really consider alternatives to VS. I realize that I can manually register msxml but I need to automatically do so.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: wix toolset to the rescue ...

Comment: I will also recommend switching to WiX for creating installations, but be aware that it is a big and complex system. On the other hand, there is a lot of online help available when you need it.